# Quickly view the type of a Swift variable in XCode

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

Is there any shortcut that will allow me to quickly view the type of any variable in Swift in XCode? Alt-Click returns "No Quick Help". Type inference is awesome, but makes life hard without tools such as these...

Comment: Unfortunately, normal IDE features that work with Objective-C still do not seem to be implemented in XCode for Swift. I think the only answer is that they will be implemented eventually.

Comment: Alt-Click works every time for me. If no type information is available, something is amiss with Source Kit, and Xcode needs to be cleaned / restarted to convince it to reprocess the code.

Comment: Yeah, restarting did the trick. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Either use Alt-click to display the declaration of the variable which displays the type at the top right like so:[image]
Or use autocompletion to show you the type:[image]

Comment: is there any way to achieve this with the keyboard only ?

Comment: Yes, by default that's command + control + ?, but you can customise the shortcut in Xcode by going to Settings > Key Bindings and searching for "Show Quick Help for Selected Item".

Comment: for those who may not know, in this context, "Alt-Click" seems to be option(⌥)-Click.