# What Is The Correct Way To Write This Multiple Condition If-Statement?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, parse-platform

What is the correct way to right this two condition if-statement?

I'm getting a compiler error that says `could not find an overload for '==' that accepts the supplied arguments`

If I use just one or the other it's fine but when I add a second one it doesn't work.

```
    for item in imageOutlets {

        if collectionObjects.count > 0 {

            let imageObject = self.collectionObjects.objectAtIndex(count) as! PFObject
            let imageFile = imageObject.objectForKey(smallThumbImage) as! PFFile
            imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in

                if (error == nil) || (imageFile != nil) {

                    item.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                } else {

                    item.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
                    println("error loading image")
                }
```

Comment: What is the data type of `error`?

Comment: @Pang it's a generic type. I updated the code for the full for-loop.

Comment: @Pang The query block won't accept an error type in arguments.

Comment: Can you check and tell us what is the data type of `error` [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26500652/1402846)?

Comment: @danh You're exactly right. The fix was to turn `imageFile` into an optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Optional variable can be nil,so change your code to this

```
 let imageFile = imageObject.objectForKey(smallThumbImage) as? PFFile
 imageFile?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({(data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
           if (error == nil){ //here do not need to check imageFile
               item.image = UIImage(data: data!)
           } else {
               item.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
               println("error loading image")
            }
})
```

Comment: Why dispatch to main?  The block runs on the main.

Comment: The fetch runs in the background, but the completion block is run on the main.

Comment: I am sure about Prase API, I have not used it before.just in case. If it works well without using GCD. You can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

As Leo notes, only optionals can be nil, and you're explicitly casting imageFile as non-optional with the `as!` operator:

```
let imageFile = imageObject.objectForKey(smallThumbImage) as! PFFile
```

You could use the `as?` operator to make imageFile optional, and your comparison should work. Even better: use `as?` with the `if-let` construct:

```
if let imageObject = self.collectionObjects.objectAtIndex(count) as? PFObject, let imageFile = imageObject.objectForKey(smallThumbImage) as? PFFile {
    //imageObject and imageFile are guaranteed to be properly cast and non-nil in this scope.
}
```

This is also safer, since using `as!` will cause a runtime error if your object can't be cast as a PFFile.